# Wireless not detected on an hp Pavilion g6 - RT5390PCIe

Tags: 11.04, wireless, networking, hardware

I just bought an HP Pavilion g6 laptop and I installed Natty Narwhal alongside Windows 7. In Windows 7, my WiFi works perfect but in Ubuntu it absolutely (no matter what I do) won't detect my home WiFi network.

Here is the output of "lspci":

```
earl@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:11.0 SATA controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M880G [Mobility Radeon HD 4200]
01:05.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RS880 Audio Device [Radeon HD 4200]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 5390
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5209 (rev 01)
earl@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Can you perhaps just post the output of this instead of an unformatted output of all pci devices: `lspci | grep network` ?

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Comment: try `lspci | grep "Network"`

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 5390

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RT5390PCIe is not directly supported by the current Natty kernel.

You will need to download some driver source code and patch the Natty kernel.

Unfortunately you need to be aware, everytime the Natty kernel is updated, you will need to repeat the following instructions:

1. Download the linux driver (RT5390PCIe) from [Ralink](http://www.ralinktech.com/support.php?s=2).
2. Extract it.  The files will be extracted to 2010_1216_RT5390_LinuxSTA_V2.4.0.4_WiFiBTCombo_DPO folder.
3. Download all the patches except the x64_86 patch, assuming you have a 32-bit system, from [opensuse](https://build.opensuse.org/package/files?package=rt5390sta&project=driver:wireless) website.
4. Copy the patches to the folder – 2010_1216_RT5390_LinuxSTA_V2.4.0.4_WiFiBTCombo_DPO
5. Goto the folder.
6. Make the following change in  /os/linux/config.mk file – HAS_ANTENNA_DIVERSITY_SUPPORT=y (originally was n)
7. Now run the following commands in terminal:

## patch instructions

```
patch -p0 < rt5390sta-2.4.0.4-config.patch
patch -p0 < rt5390sta-2.4.0.4-convert-devicename-to-wlanX.patch
patch -p0 < rt5390sta-2.4.0.4-reduce_debug_output.patch
patch -p0 < rt5390sta-2.4.0.4-remove-potential-conflicts-with-rt2860sta.patch
patch -p0 < rt5390sta-2.4.0.4-return_nonvoid_function.patch
patch -p0 < rt5390sta-2.4.0.4-WPA-mixed.patch
sudo su
cp RT2860STA.dat RT5390STA.dat
mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT5390STA
cp RT5390STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT5390STA
make clean
make
make install
modprobe rt5390sta
exit
```

[source](http://atinfinity.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/ralink-rt5390-wi-fi-driver-on-ubuntu-11-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Need to have connected to the Internet for this. Have you already gone into System->Adminstration->Hardware Drivers and Seen if any WiFi was listed if nothing was listed . i tracked down the manufacturers website and driver for you.  *http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501*  Your WiFi Card is RT5390PCIe `aka Ralink corp. Device 5390` Hope this helps!

Comment: No, only my graphics card was listed as one. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: How do I install the driver?

Comment: not sure i know you will need to compile it but i don't see a install.sh file nowhere  will  take someone with more knowledge to answer that question for you bro

Comment: Read the file Named <code> README_STA_pci </code it has build instructions in it